# One emacs.d/init.el to suit non-x session and x-session

Tags: emacs, xorg

When I start emacs without an x-server running, some of the things in my `init.el` fail, eg:

```
(require 'sr-speedbar)
```

is inappropriate without a graphical server, where I should rather start

```
(require 'speedbar)
```

What do emacs experts recommend as an appropriate `init.el` configuration in instances where emacs can be called as often from no-x modes as x-based modes?  Is there an established way to provide a general, parallel experience under either regime or graceful fallback?

Comment: `(or (featurep 'gtk) (featurep 'motif) (featurep 'x-toolkit) (featurep 'cairo))` -- e.g., in conjunction with `when` or add a `not` to the `or` statement?  Here is what I use in one of my `cond` statements on OSX to set up fonts specially for xorg:  `(and (eq system-type 'darwin) (not (featurep 'ns)) (or (featurep 'gtk) (featurep 'motif) (featurep 'x-toolkit) (featurep 'cairo)))`  Basically, you set up conditions within your `init.el` to load certain files or others when certain criteria exists or does not exist.

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you mean by "inappropriate without a graphical server"?  One thing to keep in mind is that a single Emacs session can have both GUI frames and tty frames at the very same time, so packages should be able to work both ways (rather than either way ;-).

Comment: @lawlist: Why on earth use such an ugly/complex test instead of using something like `display-graphic-p`?

Comment: @Stefan -- thank you for suggesting a more efficient method of performing this kind of test.  I may have lifted portions of the test from the function `emacs-version` or from `faces.el` a year or so ago (I don't remember exactly, but a quick Grep led me to those two possibilities).  I'll make a note on my todo-list to test out `display-graphic-p` on OSX with xorg versus regular GUI Emacs `--with-ns` and modify my user-configuration files accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot depends on what environments you typically run in and what level of
control you need. For example, if you are just wanting to distinguish between
running under a full graphics capable environment, you can use display-graphic-p
e.g.

```
(when (display-graphic-p)
  ;; do stuff which needs a graphic display)
```

However, if you need to distinguish between different platforms, such as when
running under OSX, you would need something like

```
(when (eq system-type 'darwin)
  ;; do stuff which should only run when on OSX'))
```

Finally, for situations where you need to only configure something when running
under a specific window system, you can use something like

```
(when (eq window-system 'x)
  ;; only under X window frame))
```

However, there are some subtleties to be aware of. Some of these variables, such
as window-system are a test of the current frame. So, you need to think about
when the code is executed. For example, if you run emacs as a daemon, what would
be the value of window-system at the time your init is loaded? Likewise, if you
use emacs as a daemon or use emacsclient to open a new 'frame' it may be opened
a either a graphic or a text frame. Sometimes, you may need to create a new
command which wraps around what you want to do and does the test at the point
you execute the command so that it can respond to the specific frame you are in
when you execute the command.

Comment: I guess they even provide this as an explicit suggestion in the speedbar instructions: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar